# Casting an object in Flutter/Dart returns _HashSet

Tags: flutter, dart, casting

I am having some problem in Flutter with casting a dynamic to a custom object. I receive JSON as response from a web service, which I store as an instance of my object in a class as dynamic together with some other meta information. When I try to cast that object to my desired class (e.g. LoginReply) I keep getting the following error message: `Expected a value of type 'LoginReply', but got one of type '_HashSet<LoginReply>'`

Here is my response class that stores the reply object:

```
class DioResponse {

  String? error;
  dynamic object;

  DioResponse(this.error, this.object);

  bool get isSuccessful => error == null || error!.isEmpty;

  T get<T extends dynamic>() {
    print("Object: $object");
    return object.cast<T>();
  }

}
```

I serialize the JSON response like this:

```
LoginReply _serializeResponse(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    LoginReply reply = LoginReply.fromJson(json);
    if (!reply.header!.successful) {
      errorMessage.value = "${reply.header!.errorCode}: ${reply.header!.errorMessage}";
      return LoginReply();
    }
    AppConfig.persistString("token", reply.token!);
    return reply;
  }
```

And here is how I try to access the DioReponse.object / LoginReply:

```
DioResponse response = await handler.post(Globals.nodeAddress, ......);
    if (response.isSuccessful) {
      //LoginReply reply = response.get<LoginReply>();
      print("Object: ${response.object}");
      LoginReply reply = response.object as LoginReply;
```

The print output on the second last line prints: `Object: {Instance of 'LoginReply'}` which makes the whole error even harder to understand for me.

Comment: Have you tried `response.object[0]`? Guess your object is a `Set<LoginReply>` object.

Comment: That exactly was the problem :) I just figured it out a few minutes ago after a whole day.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the closure that was passed as parameter to the post function. So it really returned a Set. I pass a function to the DioHandler class that is called there and then it just works the way it should.